# How to fix these Warnings that appear after installing Janus WebRTC and Redis on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS?

Tags: ubuntu, redis, janus-gateway

After installing **Janus WebRTC Server** by `sudo apt-get -y install janus` and **RedisPHP** using `sudo apt install redis-server` and `sudo apt-get install php-redis` on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, I run `sudo service redis status` and `sudo service redis janus`, then I get this:

```
root@host:~# sudo service redis status
● redis-server.service - Advanced key-value store
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/redis-server.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Thu 2023-04-27 03:17:22 CEST; 46min ago
       Docs: http://redis.io/documentation,
             man:redis-server(1)
   Main PID: 482768 (redis-server)
      Tasks: 4 (limit: 36043)
     Memory: 2.4M
     CGroup: /system.slice/redis-server.service
             └─482768 /usr/bin/redis-server 127.0.0.1:6379

Apr 27 03:17:22 host.mydomain.com systemd[1]: Starting Advanced key-value store...
Apr 27 03:17:22 host.mydomain.com systemd[1]: redis-server.service: Can't open PID file /run/redis/redis-server.pid (yet?) after start: Operation not permitted
Apr 27 03:17:22 host.mydomain.com systemd[1]: Started Advanced key-value store.
root@host:~# sudo service janus status
● janus.service - Janus WebRTC gateway
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/janus.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Thu 2023-04-27 03:25:39 CEST; 38min ago
       Docs: https://janus.conf.meetecho.com/docs/index.html
   Main PID: 489171 (janus)
      Tasks: 31 (limit: 36043)
     Memory: 6.3M
     CGroup: /system.slice/janus.service
             └─489171 /usr/bin/janus -o

Apr 27 03:25:39 host.mydomain.com janus[489171]: WebSockets thread started
Apr 27 03:25:39 host.mydomain.com janus[489171]: [WARN] Nanomsg server disabled (Admin API)
Apr 27 03:25:39 host.mydomain.com janus[489171]: JANUS Nanomsg transport plugin initialized!
Apr 27 03:25:39 host.mydomain.com janus[489171]: Loading transport plugin 'libjanus_http.so'...
Apr 27 03:25:39 host.mydomain.com janus[489171]: Nanomsg thread started
Apr 27 03:25:39 host.mydomain.com janus[489171]: HTTP webserver started (port 8088, /janus path listener)...
Apr 27 03:25:39 host.mydomain.com janus[489171]: [WARN] HTTPS webserver disabled
Apr 27 03:25:39 host.mydomain.com janus[489171]: [WARN] Admin/monitor HTTP webserver disabled
Apr 27 03:25:39 host.mydomain.com janus[489171]: [WARN] Admin/monitor HTTPS webserver disabled
Apr 27 03:25:39 host.mydomain.com janus[489171]: JANUS REST (HTTP/HTTPS) transport plugin initialized!
root@host:~#
```

So, observing (watching) these outputs, we can see:

**1 -** for **Redis**, this: `redis-server.service: Can't open PID file /run/redis/redis-server.pid (yet?) after start: Operation not permitted`.

**2 -** And for **Janus**, some Warnings like:

- [WARN] Nanomsg server disabled (Admin API)
- [WARN] HTTPS webserver disabled
- [WARN] Admin/monitor HTTP webserver disabled

***So, please, can anyone give advice or help to fix them ???***

Please.
I really need your help.